# New oauth2 token on each login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Hi I am using spring oauth2 as SSO, I want only one web user active at a time. If i set 
`
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

if I login from two separate browser, on both session Web application which is using oauth2 server as SSO, will continue working which is not required. Only way to solve the problem is to generate new token and delete previous token.
Let me know how we can achieve this.

`

Comment: why do you want this? that is not how tokens work. Tokens are short lived and as you already write, if that is the case you need to invalidate the current tokens and issue a new one.

Comment: My application is secured web application using spring oauth2 server, I want to impose single user  sign on. Setting maximumSessions to 1 at oauth2 server is not helping, as previously authenticated session are working fine which not required. What I want if user logged in twice only last logged session should work, but my case all are working

Comment: tokens are not sessions, please read up on what a token is, and what a session is. They are two completly different things.

Comment: But there are two sessions, one at oauth server and other at web application, I can only control oauth server session not web application session. token seems the only way to kick out stale sessions.

Comment: tokens are not sessions! when you issue a token to someone you dont start any session, there are no sessions! in the oauth world there are no sessions.

Comment: https://medium.com/@sherryhsu/session-vs-token-based-authentication-11a6c5ac45e4 so you can set how many sessions you want. Since tokens are not sessions your settings will affect nothing!

Comment: When we use oauth server as SSO then sessions comes in picture.
See this example https://github.com/juanzero000/spring-boot-oauth2-sso

Comment: when you issue a token from a SSO all you do is that you have a SINGLE sign on. One single place where all the tokens get issued from. And ONE SINGLE place that verifies the tokens.

Still there are NO sessions.

Comment: what you need to do, is to invalidate the other tokens at the SSO when someone logs in. All the settings you set is for sessions features if you use cookie sessions.

Comment: How I can invalidate after successful login ? Any idea?

Comment: i dont know your specific user case https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-revoke-tokens here you can read up

Comment: Thank I got your point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it by adding check in login success handler. In validate all existing token when same existing user login from different broker.